# Does the aria-expanded and aria-haspopup attributes apply to <select /> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

From the W3C [wiki](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-expanded_to_indicate_the_state_of_a_collapsible_element#Description)

> When authors use collapsible content, for example, to hide navigation
>   menus or lists of content, the triggering link or button should
>   indicate to screen reader users whether the collapsable content below
>   is in the expanded or in the collapsed state. The `aria-expanded`
>   attribute is used for this purpose.

Does this include `<select>` elements or is this only for navigation items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `select` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-select-element) can accept any global `aria-*` attribute, and any aria attribute applicable to the role listbox.

[`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#global-aria--attributes) is allowed for any role, and [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-expanded) is allowed for the listbox role.

Note that, the browser should already define the [default implicit semantic](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#sec-strong-native-semantics) so you do not have to care about defining an `aria` attribute to define the state of the `select` control if you're using the native element.

Comment: So if I use a plain `select` element, I do not have to add `aria-haspopup` and `aria-expanded` attributes for it to be accessible?

Comment: @Saravana yes browsers already expose the default semantic for this element