# Unable to select the aria-activedescendant combobox element in java

Tags: html, selenium, combobox

Im finding it hard to select the items from the combobox element. This combobox is something different. When i drag down the items, i could see the actual value of the item(i.e. aria-activedescendant="react-select-4--option-3"). After selecting the particular item, the value has got changed to "aria-activedescendant="react-select-4--value"". Plz suggest me the best solution to click the item. You have to specifically note this "aria-activedescendant="react-select-4--value"" in input section under html code.

Tried with below code. I was able to just click the combo box element but not the value. I used id="react-select-4--value" to click the combo box, It errors as "element not clickable at point". Technically the system understands something wrong.

```
    public void ScrollAndClickOnElement(String loacator,String LocatorValue)
{
    WebElement element = null;
    if(loacator.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelector"))
         element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorValue));
    else if(loacator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath"))
         element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorValue));
    else if(loacator.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
         element = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorValue));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
    element.click();
}

public void WaitAndClickElement(String locatorType,String locatorVaue)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);

    if(locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelector"))
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(locatorVaue))).click();


    else if(locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath"))
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locatorVaue))).click();

    else if(locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(locatorVaue))).click();
}
ScrollAndClickOnElement("id", AssessmentPageData.ElevatorManufacturer);
WaitAndClickElement("cssSelector",AssessmentPageData.Appollo);
```

Referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085027/does-the-aria-expanded-and-aria-haspopup-attributes-apply-to-select-elements) and used 'select' method, but it errors as "Element should have been "select" but was "span""

Comment: Provide more information: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? Provide error stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dev. I would like to select an item from combo box. I'm stuck because couldn't pass the right parameter from html code as the value is getting changed dynamically, and as I explained with an example above. For the same above html code, if someone brings different solution it would be greatful.

Comment: Going through your comments I understand that on clicking the combobox,  the `id` of one of the combobox item changes from `react-select-4--option-3` to `react-select-4--value`. But what's the issue in clicking the updated id?

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to use stored values of the locators. I think you still can do it using cssSelector. But you have to exactly know the changing pattern. Can you provide a bit more of the HTML DOM of the combobox items?

Comment: Please find attached the HTML DOM of the combobox. I'm sorry if I confused you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the below solution finally,

```
public void SelectBootStrap(String textval){
    WebElement listElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-menu-outer']//div[text()='"+textval+"']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",listElement);
    listElement.click();
}
```